# What is wrong with the pattern matching?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

This program is supposed to match

> (as(fd))_n

and convert it to

> \pochhammer{as(fd)}{n}

However, it is not converting the Strings correctly. It is converting

> W_n(-a^2;a,b,c,d)=(a+b)_n(a+c)_n(a+d)_n\,,

to

> W_n\pochhammer{-a^2;a,b,c,d)=(a+b}{n}\pochhammer{a+c}{n}\pochhammer{a+d}{n}\,,

when it should be converted to

> W_n(-a^2;a,b,c,d)=\pochhammer{a+b}{n}\pochhammer{a+c}{n}\pochhammer{a+d}{n}\,,

This is my code:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\((.*?)\\)_\\{([^}]+)\\})");
    Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
    StringBuffer rplcmntBfr = new StringBuffer();

    while(pochhammer.find())  {
        pochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr, "\\\\pochhammer{$2}{$3}");
    }

    pochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);  
    Pattern npochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\((.*?)\\)_(.))");
    Matcher ppochhammer = npochhammer.matcher(rplcmntBfr. toString() );
    rplcmntBfr.setLength(0);

    while(ppochhammer.find())  {
        ppochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr, "\\\\pochhammer{$2}{$3}");
    }

    ppochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);
    writer.println(rplcmntBfr);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `match (as(fd))_n` - can you elaborate on this? Obviously you don't mean that literal string, given your example; what is it you're trying to match?

Comment: If you have nested parens, java's regex can't handle those as of right now.

Comment: Jerry is right, the only way to find balanced parenthesis is to use a third party regex library that supports recursion or to write your own parser.

Comment: @OP check my updated answer, especially part about `.*?` vs `[^)]*`.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken but maybe you are looking for something like

```
String replaced = line.replaceAll("\\(([^)]*)\\)_(\\w+)", "\\\\pochhammer{$1}{$2}");
//                                                ^^^^ 
//                                  You can use \\d or \\d+ instead
//                                  this part. I am not sure what `n` can be
```

I can try to correct my answer when you describe your question in more detail, like what you are trying to achieve with your first loop? Replacing `"(\\((.*?)\\)_\\{([^}]+)\\})"` with `\\\\pochhammer{$2}{$3}` seems pointless here since there are no `(xxx)_{n}` in your input.

So only problem seems to be with your second regex which is `(\\((.*?)\\)_(.))`. If you take a closer look at it you don't need your outer brackets because they will just make group 1 group 2, so instead of

```
    (\\((.*?)\\)_(.)) you can use 
     \\((.*?)\\)_(.)
```

Next thing is that you are using `.*?` which means can match any characters so `\\((.*?)\\)_` will match any character first `(` and last `)` which has `_` after it like in your case

```
 W_n(-a^2;a,b,c,d)=(a+b)_n(a+c)_n(a+d)_n\,,
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     this part
```

which in result gives you

```
 W_n\pochhammer{-a^2;a,b,c,d)=(a+b}{n}\pochhammer{a+c}{n}\pochhammer{a+d}{n}\,,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To solve this problem you can use `[^)]` instead of `.` like in my solution at top of my answer. This way you will only match single, not nested set of parenthesis like `(xxx)` because `x` in this case can't be `)` (`[^)]` means - every character except `)`).

Comment: From your sourcecode the search expression should be \\(([^)]*)\\)_(.)

Comment: @wumpz Sorry, what? And why `.`? I don't want part after `_` to be any character like `(` for instance. `\\w` or `\\d` seems more appropriate there.

Comment: He used in his sources `(\\((.*?)\\)_(.))` or am I mistaken here. But you are right, if you avoid `(` matching there. Its safer.

Comment: @wumpz Yes, OP did use it, but that is his/her sourcecode, not mine (which confused me in your comment). Also OP used `.` while I am proposing something more detailed. Another point is that OP is using `while` loops with appendReplacement and appendTail where it can be replaced with simple `replaceAll`. I realise it may be optimization because in OP code there is only one StringBuffer, but code readability also matters.

Comment: @Pshemo, Thanks for taking your time for answering. I get why it is converting weirdly now. However, the reason why I used . is to match nested parentheses too. Now i realize that does not work. Do you have an idea of how to match nested parentheses too? Because [^)] will not match a nested parentheses. Thanks.

Comment: @Pshemo, Also, I can't use the replaceAll method because the matcher groups are all replaced at once with that method, which would result in the output being: W_n(-a^2;a,b,c,d)=\pochhammer{a+b}{n}\pochhammer{a+b}{n}\pochhammer{a+b}{n}\, in the example mentioned above.

Comment: @user2825125 As pointed by others in comments you cant parse recuresively with Java regex. Your will need to write your own parser which will iterate over your input. You can use stack to hold positions of potential `(` and `)`. If you will find `)` which has `_n` after it you can just get last position of found `(` to decide that you want to replace part between it with `\pochhammer{xxx}{n}`.